# How to convert a apache url rewrite rule to IIS rule?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, iis, url-rewriting

I have url rewrite rule on my .htaccess file like this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(scripts|css)/(.+)\.(.+)\.(js|css)$ $1/$2.$4 [L]
```

I need to use the same rule on my IIS .

I have used `^(.*)\.[\d]{10}\.(css|js)` for the pattern.
I am not sure what to mention `Rewrite URL`.

I want to rewrite the url `/css/structure.1234.css` as `/css/structure.css`

Anyone knows please help?

Answer (score 2):

I read your other ColdFusion question (regarding using regex to add a numerical value to a filename.)

We use an underscore and a 14 digit datestamp.  Here's the IIS Rewrite Rule that we use. You can modify it for your needs.

```
<rule name="CSSJSDatestamp" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)(_[0-9]{14}\.)(css|js)$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{SCRIPT_NAME}" pattern="/_scripts/" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.{R:3}" />
</rule>
```

BTW, I don't use this method anymore with my ColdFusion-drive websites since installing IISpeed (PageSpeed for IIS).  It automatically minifies, concats and caches JS/CSS files when the files are changed (without the need for cach-busting). It can also optimize images based on device support (ie, reduce size, auto-conversion to WebP, etc).  I also really like that it can move all CSS & JSS to the HEAD of the HTML file, prioritize CSS and lazy loads all images "below the fold" with having to add any ColdFusion code or use jQuery.

For more info on IISpeed/Pagespeed, check out:

- http://www.iispeed.com/
- http://www.iispeed.com/pagespeed/insights
- https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/